# Is it important to have chess as part of the education in schools?

Tags: learning

Some countries like Russia have chess as school matter.
I was wondering if it could be as important as the other topics of a normal curriculum, considering that the importance of disciplines is the generation of constructive minds of our children.

Answer (score 3):

The [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/educationnews/10770373/Chess-should-be-compulsory-in-primary-schools.html) ran a story supporting the benefits of learning chess. Here is the summary for the 'for' camp:

> Pupils as young as seven should be given compulsory lessons in chess amid claims it boosts concentration levels, numeracy and reading comprehension, according to a teachers’ leader.

From the limited research I've done, articles like this do not highlight the 'against' camp, so I will construct my own argument for why chess may not be included on the syllabus:

1. **Limited class time**. Class time could be spent on existing subjects (reading, writing, arithmetic), or spent on many other worthy 'new' subjects (computing, citizenship, financial awareness etc.). It becomes a trade off between what we want to teach the next generation with the limited time they have in school
2. **Uncertainty of transferable skills**. In the quote above it's claimed that chess improves numeracy skills. But surely studying mathematics would be a more direct way to do this?
3. **Level of popularity**. In the UK, football/soccer is arguably the national sport. There just wouldn't be many pupils that would want to study chess, nor many teachers of a suitable callibre